# Calculate stock value based on two previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I have been kinda stuck on this all day.
I want to calculate the current stock weight based one the previous row
But its a lot more challenging then I thought it would be.

My data looks as follows

| weight | balans | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 50 | 2021-10-15 |
| 0 | -30 | 2021-10-14 |
| 0 | 120 | 2021-10-13 |

I want to calculate the weight (current stock) based on the balans from the previous row so that it will look like this:

| weight | balans | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 50 | 2021-10-15 |
| 550 | -30 | 2021-10-14 |
| 520 | 120 | 2021-10-13 |
| 650 | -233 | 2021-10-12 |

Any help or tips are more then welcome!

Comment: What is the logic of calculations, what code have you tried do far?

Comment: Based on the tags, is this data stored in a numpy dataframe? Or are you reading it in from a CSV? If you can post any code you have for context that might help.

Comment: Do it in Excel instead?

Comment: df['new_weight'] = df['balans'].cumsum() + df['weight'].iloc[0] ?

Comment: I suppose at `2021-10-13` weight should be 520?

Comment: I can query the data from a SQL database into a pandas dataframe. We don't keep a stock history, just a current one and I want to backtrack and visualize the stock over a time period. its + 100.000 rows.

Comment: @ipj you're right! see why I need you guys :)

Comment: Thanks @alex314159 your solutions works! I have a feeling that I can solve this problem in a better way. My sql skills are nog good enough to solve it straight from the source.